# Store function in database with mongodb in meteor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I know that [in mongodb there is a way to save a function in the database](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/). I am trying to do something similar in Meteor, where I create a collection that registers callbacks for given matching regular expressions. That is: a structure like so.

```
{
  socket: 'messages',
  event: XRegExp(`^
    (?<component>Arm)
    (?<x>\d)(?<y>\d)(?<z>\d)
  $`, 'x'),
  handler: function (component, x, y, z) {
    console.log('Arm moved moved to position: ${x} ${y} ${z}');
  }
}
```

However, I cannot save the function to the database. I essentially want to take the `exec` regex and apply the args to `handler`.

Is it possible to save a function to a mongo database with meteor?

Comment: Even per the link you provide MongoDB can only store functions in a special collection. So you wouldn't be able to do what you describe even in mongodb directly. I think your best bet is to store the function as a string and use `eval` to turn it back into a function when you need it.

Comment: However you can store functions in the monod DB, But its recommended to separate the application logic and the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work.

```
MyCollection = new Meteor.Collection('mycollection', {
  transform: function(x) {
    var y = _.extend({}, x);
    y.handler = new Function("return " + x.handler)();
    return y;
  }
});

MyCollection.insert({
  socket: 'messages',
  event: XRegExp(`^
    (?<component>Arm)
    (?<x>\d)(?<y>\d)(?<z>\d)
  $`, 'x'),
  handler: myfunction.toString()
});
```

Comment: nice! thanks, the transform was the missing component